# Rotated elements in the grid - breaks the distribution

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I divided the grid into:

- 2 columns
- 2 rows

(0,0) -> element

(0,1) -> vertical dimension

(1,0) -> horizontal dimension

The horizontal dimension is working properly

What to do to get the same effect for a vertical dimension?
Rotating elements spoils the entire system. I've tried with different settings and can not find the right solution.

It is also important that when scaling FontSize remains constant.

Everything is in the ViewBox, the lengths are dynamically inserted.

```
<Viewbox Name="MainVB">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Rectangle Width="{Binding SRW}" Height="20" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="Black" Fill="#FFBADCD0"/>
                        <Rectangle Width="{Binding A}" Height="{Binding HF}" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" StrokeThickness="0.5" Stroke="Black" Fill="#FF7E7738"/>
                        <Rectangle Width="{Binding A}" Height="{Binding BWR}" Margin="0,-0.5,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" StrokeThickness="0.5" Stroke="Black" Fill="Goldenrod"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" >
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock FontSize="{Binding ElementName=MainVB, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource conv}}" Margin="-20,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"><Run Text="{Binding A}"/> cm</TextBlock>
                        <Path Width="{Binding A}" Height="10" Margin="20,-5,0,0" StrokeThickness="0.4" Stroke="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M0,5 L100,5 M0,0 L0,10 M100,0 L100,10" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Vertical" Background="#FFBF8F8F" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="{Binding ElementName=MainVB, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource conv}}" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"><Run Text="{Binding A}"/> cm</TextBlock>
                        <Path Width="{Binding L}" Height="10" Margin="0,0,0,0" StrokeThickness="0.4" Stroke="Black" Data="M0,5 L100,5 M0,0 L0,10 M100,0 L100,10" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>
```

[image: Foto]

Comment: Set LayoutTransform instead of RenderTransform.

Comment: @Clemens , Works, thanks :)

Comment: @Clemens Do you know how to solve the problem: At the moment when changing the size of the element in the ViewBox, FontSize is fixed but when I change the size of the element dynamically, the font is already changing. I would like to always have a fixed font size